# How to access each element in object in google.colab?

Tags: python, list, file, key, google-colaboratory

I uploaded a file in googl colab and I tried to get the name of the file

This is a result when I print `upload.keys()`:

`dict_keys(['SSE.csv', 'SSE_origin.csv'])`

I tried to access each element of object.
I only find this solution.

```
from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()

for name in uploaded.keys():
    print(name)
```

Is there any other solution like indexing?

Comment: Not sure I understand what is your question and what's wrong with your current code

Comment: Also I'm not sure what does `google.colab` has to do with anything... `uploaded` seems to be a simple dict so everything around is just noise. Try to post a [mre] and clarify what is your question and your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have a dict_keys object, not a list. To use it as a list you have to convert it:

```
list(uploaded.keys())
```

Now you can access each element by indexing

Comment: Hey @sungho. Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the most helpful answer.

Comment: sorry I didn't know that